# Regular expression capability in AWS-Neptune using Gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I was trying to simulate the "like" search in Neptune using Gremlin. However it is not it.get() function in Neptune. The other graphs like JanusGraph has this available. Is there any alternative for this in Neptune. When we try applying the filter options on the Gremlin provided sample graphs it is working fine. However it doesn't work with Neptune. For e.g. following query works in Gremlin provided sample graph however it doesn't work in Neptune.

g.V().filter{it.get().value('name').matches(".*o.*")}

g.V().filter{it.get().value('name').matches(".*o.*")} query working with Factory provided graph in Gremlin. Neptune it was not identifying it.get()

Answer (score 2):

in your example above you are essentially sending in-line code (Groovy lambdas) to the Graph engine. It is common for hosted graph databases such as Neptune to not allow the submission of such in-line code snippets for a variety of reasons. Apache TinkerPop 3.4 takes a first step towards adding additional text searching predicates to the Gremlin language itself and avoiding the need for such lambda function usage. Once Neptune has support for Apache Tinkerpop 3.4 you will be able to do things such as `startingWith`, `endingWith` and `contains` searches.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, thanks for the response. Does it mean that  Groovy lambdas will be removed (since is included in gremlin 3.4) as soon as they started supported gremlin 3.4?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question but as far as I know there are no plans to deprecate lambdas from TinkerPop any time soon. They are just not supported by all graph databases.

Comment: @SivaKumar Please, do not forget to mark the answer as accepted :-) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers can guide you if needed